# Advanced using of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am confused about using advanced for loop and trying to make the flow clear.

For example, I have the main data frame like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  ... year
0  0  1  1  2  ... 1991
1  0  0  0  1  ... 1993
2  1  0  0  0  ... 1994
3  0  1  1  0  ... 1995
```

I already had a table of percentage containing each element like this:

```
  index   value
0   A     0.002
1   B     0.012
2   C     0.035
3   D     0.005
...
```

I want to calculate conditional probabilities for each of the keys like this:

```
  key1  key2  year  prob
0  A     B    1991  0.135
1  A     C    1993  0.500
2  A     B    1994  0.354
3  A     A    1991  1.000
```

I am confused about the year column and the elements. How to use for loop to extract elements from columns of the main data frame?

There's another way I am thinking about, but don't know how to start it. I get key1 and key2 from the percentage table then create a range for the year (range(1983, …), then get the prob from conditional probabilities function.

```
def condprobability(frame, column1, column2, year):
    for i in range(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995):
```

I'm stuck here. May I ask for some hints or resources about it?

Comment: FYI `for` loops aren't generally advisable with pandas. You can almost always achieve the same outcome much more cleanly with pandas functions like [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) on each row and calculate conditional probability between each column。

```py
percent_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)

columns_to_cal_cond_prob = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cond_probs = []

for index, row in main_df.iterrows():
    for col1 in columns_to_cal_cond_prob:
        for col2 in columns_to_cal_cond_prob:
            value1 = main_df.loc[index, col1]
            value2 = main_df.loc[index, col2]

            # Implement your conditional probabilities calculations here
            cond_prob = percent_df.loc[col1, 'value'] + percent_df.loc[col2, 'value']

            cond_probs.append([col1, col2, main_df.loc[index, 'year'], cond_prob])

cond_prob_df = pd.DataFrame(cond_probs, columns=['key1', 'key2', 'year', 'prob'])
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using pandas start with loc and iloc.